# Solaris 11.3 dladm: could not open /dev/dld: operation failed

Tags: solaris

After update (i think, but may be something else) from Solaris 11.1 to 11.3, dladm and dlstat commands was broken. Invoking dladm or dlstat gives error:

```
$ dladm
dladm: could not open /dev/dld: operation failed
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What's the output from `ls -lad /dev/dld` and `ls -Ll /dev/dld`?

Comment: `root@CFTTEST:~# ls -lad /dev/dld`
`lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          27 Dec  7  2013 /dev/dld -> ../devices/pseudo/dld@0:ctl`
`root@CFTTEST:~# ls -Ll /dev/dld`
`crw-rw-rw-   1 root     sys       48,  0 Dec 26  2016 /dev/dld`

Comment: What's the output from `grep dld /etc/name_to_major`?  You should see output like `dld 48`. What's the output from `grep dld /etc/minor_perm`? You should see `dld: * 0666 root sys`.  If those are correct, run `truss -o /path/to/some/output/file dladm`, find `write(2,` in the output file - which is where it emits the "operation failed" error message and see what it's trying to do. The OpenSolaris source code can be found at http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/dladm/dladm.c#1461 and http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/lib/libdladm/common/libdladm.c#97

Comment: From the OpenSolaris code (which is somewhat different from the Solaris 11.3 code because the OpenSolaris code *always* needs an argument and doesn't default to `show-link` as the Solaris 11 code does), the only way to get the `dladm: could not open /dev/dld: operation failed` error message is for the call to `open( "/dev/dld" ... );` to fail with an unexpected `errno`.  The Solaris 11 code likely behaves the same, which means something unexpected is going on.  Hence the `truss` command to find out what that unexpected `errno` actually is.

Answer (score 1):

Check the service status:

```
# svcs -av
svcs: Could not bind to repository server: repository server unavailable. Exiting.
```

CAUSE:
Checking the services status shows the the repository daemon was not up:

SOL:
Send a SIGTERM to svc.startd.
That will cause svc.startd to restart and spawn a new svc.configd daemon that remains under control of svc.startd

```
# /lib/svc/bin/svc.configd
```

to refresh the repository

Comment: I'm impressed.  There were lots of `svc.startd`s so I did a `kill -TERM` on the one with the `-s` and it also had the smallest PID.